# What will be the level of const-ness in this situation?

Tags: c++

when `ptr` is a `const` pointer and also a pointer to `const int`, how will it behave while copying its value into other pointers to `const int` or `const pointers`? Will be **top-level** or **low-level**?

Comment: I don't see your problem, write a code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use:

```
     int var=8;
     int const *low = &var;              //Low level const
     const int *const high_low = low;    //Both High & Low level const present
```

In the above code, both high_low & low behaves as Low-level const.

But in this code:

```
     int var=8;
     const int *const high_low = &var;
     int const *low=&var;
     high_low = low;                     //Error: high_low behaves as High-Level const where as Low is Low-Level const
```

The problem is that you are seeing it in terms of high & low level const rather than **whether a variable can be changed or not** - **that solves the problem**